# Define weight for completion suggest field in elasticsearch-dsl

Tags: django, python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl

Using Elastic Search 5.2.x and elasticseach-dsl for bulk index creation in my Django app, I am trying to implement a completion suggest field like so:

```
def indexing(self):
       obj = SchoolIndex(
          meta = {'id': self.pk},
          name = self.name,
          name_suggest = self.name
       )
       obj.save(index="school_index")
       return obj.to_dict(include_meta=True)
```

Now, I need to define some weights for the suggest field-name_suggest, so that the suggestions get scored during querying, but I am not able to figure out elasticsearch-dsl specific syntax to do the same in the function above.

I tried doing this, but it didn't work :

```
name_suggest = {'input':self.name,'weight':100}
```

Essentially, I am trying to implement in Django, what the docs show here :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-suggesters-completion.html#indexing

I am new to Elastisearch, please advise if I am assigning the weight at the right place in code and the syntax to do it in Django.

Thanks.

Comment: There's some sample code here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/52f329e5089b64062102601fec41a612c43b1910/examples/completion.py

Comment: Can you upload the mapping for index ?

Answer (score 0):

For others' reference, following is a working method to index with weights:

```
def indexing(self):
       obj = SchoolIndex(
          meta = {'id': self.pk},
          name = self.name,
          name_suggest = {'input': self.name, 'weight': 10}
       )
       obj.save(index="school_index")
       return obj.to_dict(include_meta=True)
```

With the above, the scores will be boosted based on the weights.